# Subtract string value in col1 from col2 and populate col2

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, tr

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
MASTER          APP                        SET       STATUS
max_mstr_ref    max_mstr_ref_horizon_biz   pp_script     true
max_mstr_ref    max_mstr_ref_horizon_biz   pp_scrpt_1    false
max_retl_len    max_retl_len_bddm_biz      px_script     true
min_min_ref     min_min_ref_HZ_Null        ap_script_2   false
...
```

What I need to do is remove the repetitive prefix values in column 2 (e.g. `max_mstr_ref`, `max_retl_len`, `min_min_ref` and dozens more like it from the prefixes in column 2).  I was thinking there has to subtract the value in column 1 from the value in column 2 and populate column 2 with the result. This would have to be done dynamically for each record in the file.

I tried some `awk` methods but keep comping up short.

Comment: I didn't see any C's in the input, so I dropped the csv tag for now.

Comment: Ahhh thx Jeff... should have been .tsv.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
awk '{sub($1"_", "", $2); printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' _input_file_
```

This uses the first field as a regular expression to be removed from the second field.  The 4 fields are then printed out.  I included "_" in the regular expression since I did not think you wanted that.  You can adjust the printf format string to beautify the output.

Comment: Hey Lewis thanks for the response but I can't seem to get this to work.  can you possibly break down how this command works?  Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm.  Thought I did.  :)    So, the sub($1"_", "", $2) function uses $1, the first field, with an underscore appended as the regular expression.  It matches this regular expression against $2, the second field.  If there is a match, it will replace it with "" (i.e. it will replace $1_ with a blank string).  So, if field 2 starts with field1, it is removed from field 2.  That is your subtraction you were looking for.  After that substitution is done, it just prints out the 4 fields.

Answer (score 0):

If that prefix is ALWAYS present, try

```
awk 'NR == 1 || sub ($1 "_", "", $2)' OFS="\t" file
MASTER          APP         SET         STATUS
max_mstr_ref    horizon_biz pp_script   true
max_mstr_ref    horizon_biz pp_scrpt_1  false
max_retl_len    bddm_biz    px_script   true
min_min_ref     HZ_Null     ap_script_2 false
```